# Transforming React State Object into correct JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on a nifty todo application with React and  just starting out with a working example I am setting up sample data state like this:

```
this.state = {
  Task: [{
      name: "Art",
      items: [{
          item: 'Work on glazing technique',
          isDone: false,
          dateCompleted: ""
        },
        {
          item: 'Prank call Dali and hang up',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/15/2018"
        },
        {
          item: 'Prepare new Masonite panels',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/15/2018"
        },
        {
          item: 'Purchase sable brush',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/15/2018"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Music",
      items: [{
          item: 'Work on Symphony',
          isDone: false,
          dateCompleted: ""
        },
        {
          item: 'Finish Berklee class',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/12/2018"
        },
        {
          item: 'Practice guitar',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/10/2018"
        },
        {
          item: 'Build new studio',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/10/2108"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Writing",
      items: [{
          item: 'Finish novel structure',
          isDone: false,
          dateCompleted: ""
        },
        {
          item: 'Work on middle part',
          isDone: true,
          dateCompleted: "07/08/2018"
        },
        {
          item: 'Puchase some index cards',
          isDone: true,
          dataCompleted: "07/08/2018"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  filter: [{
    keyword: '',
    Status: "SHOW_ALL"
  }],
  selectedProject: "0"
};
```

So, I am at the point now, where I am going to setup axios and read in my data via JSON, instead of setting it explicitly. And of course next step will be setting up express and read/write JSON to database.

But in translating my Task Object to JSON, I am not doing well. This is what I have so far:

```
{
  "name": "Art",
  "items": [{
      "item": "Work on glazing technique",
      "isDone": "false"
    },
    {
      "item": "Prank call Dali and hang up",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Prepare new Masonite panels",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Purchase sable brush",
      "isDone": "true"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Music",
  "items": [{
      "item": "Work on Symphony",
      "isDone": "false"
    },
    {
      "item": "Finish Berklee class",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Practice guitar",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Build new studio",
      "isDone": "true"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Writing",
  "items": [{
      "item": "Finish novel structure",
      "isDone": "false"
    },
    {
      "item": "Work on middle part",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Puchase some index cards",
      "isDone": "true"
    },
    {
      "item": "Install Scrivener",
      "isDone": "true"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "filter": [{
    "keyword": "",
    "Status": "SHOW_ALL"
  }],
  "selectedCatelog": 0
}
```

At the first instance of closing `}, {` it throws an error on import saying:

```
syntax error, encountered comma
```

strangely enough the JSON validator says my JSON is valid. I am not constructing my JSON correctly.

Basically I think I have a collection here. A Dictionary of multiple items of key value pairs and the second one "items" is an array of items.

I am sure it is very simple to structure this correctly, but could someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need your json object to start with an array? Most of the data I pass around in redux are arrays. Your object appears to be an object, while Task appears to accept an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json you posted is not valid (you can check it [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)), it seems that you want to present a list of objects.

Hence you will need to wrap the entire thing with an array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Art",
    "items": [
      {
        "item": "Work on glazing technique",
        "isDone": "false"
      },
      {
        "item": "Prank call Dali and hang up",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Prepare new Masonite panels",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Purchase sable brush",
        "isDone": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Music",
    "items": [
      {
        "item": "Work on Symphony",
        "isDone": "false"
      },
      {
        "item": "Finish Berklee class",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Practice guitar",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Build new studio",
        "isDone": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Writing",
    "items": [
      {
        "item": "Finish novel structure",
        "isDone": "false"
      },
      {
        "item": "Work on middle part",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Puchase some index cards",
        "isDone": "true"
      },
      {
        "item": "Install Scrivener",
        "isDone": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "filter": [
      {
        "keyword": "",
        "Status": "SHOW_ALL"
      }
    ],
    "selectedCatelog": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks a bunch!  Yes, the JSON Linter betrayed me.  It wasn't valid.  I see what I was doing wrong.  It's just a bunch of separate objects the way I was implementing.

Answer (score 0):

these are all separate objects, you never wrap the entire thing at all to make it a single json object. It's just a bunch of objects separated by commas.

```
//you never wrap the json with an opener
    {//start
        "name": "Art",
        "items": [{
                "item": "Work on glazing technique",
                "isDone": "false"
            },
            {
                "item": "Prank call Dali and hang up",
                "isDone": "true"
            },
            {
                "item": "Prepare new Masonite panels",
                "isDone": "true"   
            },
            {
                "item": "Purchase sable brush",
                "isDone": "true"
            }]
    } //end of object
    ,//then a comma
    { //start of an object
        "name": "Music",
        "items": [{
                "item": "Work on Symphony",
                "isDone": "false"
            },
            {
                "item": "Finish Berklee class",
                "isDone": "true"
            },
            {
                "item": "Practice guitar",
                "isDone": "true"   
            },
            {
                "item": "Build new studio",
                "isDone": "true"
            }]
    }//end
    ,//then comma
 {//etc....
        "name": "Writing",
        "items": [{
                "item": "Finish novel structure",
                "isDone": "false"
            },
            {
                "item": "Work on middle part",
                "isDone": "true"
            },
            {
                "item": "Puchase some index cards",
                "isDone": "true"   
            },
            {
                "item": "Install Scrivener",
                "isDone": "true"
            }]
    },{
    "filter":[
            { 
                "keyword": "", 
                "Status": "SHOW_ALL" 
            }],
                "selectedCatelog": 0
     }
//close json here
```

Comment: Actually, the json you posted isn't valid as well.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I know, I was showing him where his mistake was because I can't write a comment that long.

Comment: Ok, was just making sure, so others won't get confused.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for your comments and explanation